# statistics -problem with normal distribution table

Tags: statistics

am having difficulty reading z-table distribution. for instance, i have this

$$ Z_{0.02} = -2.05 $$ and $$ Z_{0.99} = 2.33 $$

i want to know how the values were gotten.

thanks, appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following table from a book:

[image]

You are looking for $Z_{0.02}$ and $Z_{0.99}$

Note that the notation $Z_{0.99}=2.33$ actually stands for: $Z_{\text{'a probability'}}=\text{'a Z value'}$ or in other words:

$Z_{0.99}=2.33$ 'states' that the random variable $Z$ takes on a value equal or smaller than  $2.33$ with probability $0.99$.

Which is the same as: $P(Z\leq 2.33)=0.99$
(This holds for the table above: other tables may use $P(Z\geq \cdots)=$ 'a probability)'

Now the rows in the table indicate the first decimal place of a $Z$-value and the columns indicate the second decimal place.

The values that we find in the table is the $P(X\leq z_{\alpha})=\text{'a probability'}$

So $Z_{\alpha}=2.33$:

- first number and first decimal place is $2.3$: row 24
- second decimal place is $3$: column 4
  $\ \ \ \Rightarrow \text{Hence the probability is } \mathbf{0.9901}$

The other way around is:

$Z_{0.99}=a$:

- Look in the table which value is closest to 0.99 $\Rightarrow Z=2.33$

For the other $z$ value you can do something like this:
so for example $P(X \leq \alpha)=-2.05$ so $1-P(X \leq \alpha)=1--2.05=1.205$

Comment: > "$Z_{0.99}=2.33$ 'states' that the random variable $Z$ takes on value $2.33$ with probability $0.99$."  This assertion is incorrect. The next statement which asserts that $P(Z \leq 2.33) = 0.99$ is correct, and if the first were true, then it would mean that $P(Z < 2.33) = 0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: yes of course. It's hard to explain CDF and pdf with words.. I will change it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your table is organized. Here's one such [table](http://www.math.unb.ca/~knight/utility/NormTble.htm).

1. To find $Z_{0.02}$, we must find $k$ such that:
   $$Pr(Z < k)=0.02 \iff Pr(Z<-k)=1-0.02=0.98$$
   Looking along the "$2.0$" row and the "$0.05$" and "$0.06$" columns, we find the numbers $0.9798$ and $0.9803$. Since $0.98$ is closer to the first number, we conclude that $$Pr(Z<2.05)=0.9798...\approx0.98 \implies Z_{0.02}=k\approx-2.05$$
2. To find $Z_{0.99}$, we must find $k$ such that:
   $$Pr(Z < k)=0.99$$
   Looking along the "$2.3$" row and the "$0.02$" and "$0.03$" columns, we find the numbers $0.9898$ and $0.9901$. Since $0.99$ is closer to the second number, we conclude that $$Pr(Z<2.33)=0.9901...\approx0.99 \implies Z_{0.99}=k\approx2.33$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is standard normal,
$$P(X\leqslant-2.05)\approx0.02,\qquad P(X\leqslant2.33)\approx0.99.$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on your notation, the percentile $z_{\alpha}$ can be defined as the unique value of $X$ such that:
$P(X \leq z_{\alpha}) = \alpha $